# How can I use a txt file in an Array iOS Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsstring, readfile

I am trying to use data from a txt file in an array to display on different TextViews dependent on the TableCell selected. How can I use the txt file below in an array?

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("HelloWorldProgramming", ofType: "txt")

    if let content = String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {

        TextView.text = content
    }
```

Comment: Is der any pattern in your txt file.Like the data(words etc ) are seperated by any component in txt file

Comment: @BananaB please clarify how the .txt file is structured and how you would like to separate it by (i.e. space, hyphen, new line, etc.)

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder its just a .txt file with a paragraph that I am wanting to display in TextView.. not too sure if that makes sense..

Comment: @BananaB can you specify what happens when you run your current code?

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder when I run this current code it reads the .txt file .. but I am asking, How can I go about taking that sequence of txt from the .txt file and use it in an array? specifically a tableView Array?

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder for example instead of:

`ThirdTableArray = [ThirdTable(ThirdTitle:["Hello World Programming","The Compiling Process","Program Errors and Warnings"]),`

how can I change "Hello World Programming" String to display the text from the .txt file

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder   thanks for the help, I actually just placed it in the wrong ViewController. Its working now. But, How can I change the txt using an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate each line of the text file as a string in an array like so:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("HelloWorldProgramming", ofType: "txt")
if let content = String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
    let arrayOfLines = content.componentsSeparatedByString( "\n" )
}
```

Comment: lets say I have two .txt files I want to merge to display at the same time. How would you do that? would I use arrayOfLines?

Comment: If you wrap this up in a function that returns an array given a filename in the bundle, something like `func arrayFromFile( filename: String ) -> [String]`, then you can just concatenate them with the `+` operator: `let combinedFiles = arrayFromFile( "file1") + arrayFromFile( "file2" )`.  You'll have to sort out how and where you unwrap your optional values, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks ! That makes a lot of sense.